# Android PHP и мгновенные сообщения. Сокеты?

Tags: php, android, сокет

Есть задача реализовать возможность пользователям Android приложений обмениваться сообщениями друг с другом. Например как WatsApp или VK. Просто тет-а-тет общение, с отображением, что собеседник набирает сообщение. Без аудио/видео звонков. Что бы был список контактов, т.е. пользователь может общаться с одним человеком, а в фоне ему приходят сообщения от другого пользователя.

В моем распоряжении PHP сервер.
Вариант через БД с обращением через интервал времени мне кажется крайне неверный. 
История переписки будет храниться на сервере скорее всего.

Я думаю что необходимо использовать сокеты (но ранее я с ними не работал, и видел лишь краем глаза).

UPDATE: Незнаю как поступить, закрыть вопрос или дополнить его тут?
В общем, я не думаю что одним сообщением получиться ответить на данный вопрос. Но я буду очень благодарен, если дадите информацию о том, что и где почитать. Алгоритм примерный реализации чата на сокетах.

Comment: Всё верно, Вам нужны сокеты!

Comment: Удобнее будет использовать централизированный обмен сообщениями через notifications сервис типа Firebase. Там можно будет делать необходимые проверки и пересылать данные нужному(ым) клиентам через push уведомления.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov А разве watsApp или Android версия ВКонтакте работает именно с push уведомлениями? Мне кажется push не для этого предназначен. Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Push работает с сокетами, это постоянная связь, по которой сервер шлет уведомления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши варианты для транспорта (если нужен свой сервер):

- WebSockets(например чтобы потом можно было и веб сделать и будет fallback через proxy) + Push - пуши нужны чтобы разбудить Android
  На сервере, например посмотрите обзор: https://habr.com/post/331462/
  На клиенте OKHTTP https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/web-sockets-now-shipping-in-okhttp-3-5-463a9eec82d1
- сырые сокеты - например вам поможет ReactPHP - не хуже ноды будет
  https://sergeyzhuk.me/2017/06/22/reactphp-chat-server/

Также вы можете все таки использовать внешний сервис например Firebase - на стороне сервера делаете  проброс логики до вашего PHP сервиса. Также стоит посмотреть на https://pusher.com/